# Is it too much to allocate 16kb on the stack?

Tags: c++, c, stack, memory-management

I need to instantiate a char[16384] buffer before calling a c function. After the function returns I will read some parts of it and discard it.

Is it ok to allocate it on the stack or should I use the heap?

**EDIT:** I'll add some information. The code will run on several platforms, from PC to iPhone, where I guess the stack space will not be so big, but I have no idea about that.

Comment: what system and why not malloc?

Comment: it's likely to be fine, but depends on your platform and what else is going on in your program.

Comment: it depends.  you can always change stack size on regular x86(-64).  may be different for embedded

Comment: I would not say it's too much. But put it on the heap anyway, because there it is more difficult to abuse buffer overruns.

Comment: Is this code re-entrant? How many threads will be calling the function/method?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's hard to give a definitive yes or no to this question because the answer is highly dependent on your environment and at what point in the program the function which allocates the memory is invoked.

Personally though if I saw this in a code review I'd raise a red flag.  That's a lot of memory to be using for a stack based buffer.  It may work today in the very specific place you're using it but what about tomorrow when you're called with a much bigger stack below you?  Or when the customer hits a scenario you didn't consider?

But like I said it's scenario dependent and it may be just fine for your specific scenario.  There's simply not enough detail in your question to say yes or no

Comment: +1: code that uses so much stack space is not reliably reusable in large programs with deep nesting.

Comment: Unless you can tolerate `malloc` failure, allocation on the stack is probably *more* reliable. Unless you use recursion (Considered Harmful, at least when it's beyond `O(log n)`), static analysis can determine the total amount of stack space needed by the program and prove that you will never have a stack overflow. On the other hand, `malloc` could fail for plenty of conditions, most of which are data-dependent in most programs and cannot be ruled out. I would use stack allocation when a small bounded buffer is needed, whenever you can be sure it's safe.

Comment: @R..: this is a bit like saying that cycling on the pavement is actually _safer_ than on the road. This selfdestructs as all cyclists subsequently use the pavement // Static analysis becomes less useful with polymorphism, firstclass function objects and meta-programming/runtime code generation etc. Last time I checked static analysis for c++ stopped more or less at the 'too hard to reliably parse' stage (i.e. unless very tightly integrated in IDE, it will be virtually impossible to have confidence that the actual preprocessed source for analysis matches the compiled source).

Comment: @R..: "I would use stack allocation when a small bounded buffer is needed". Of course, anyone would. The question is whether 16k is "small". I've used systems with default stack sizes down to about 4k, so IMO the questioner needs to find out about the systems he actually needs to support, rather than asking us to guess ;-)

Comment: @Steve: That's what I addressed in my answer. :-) Aside from the few cases I mentioned, 16k is pretty damn small.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you're programming for embedded systems, code which might be running from a thread other than the main thread, or code which is called recursively, I would say 16k is well within the reasonable size you can allocate on the stack.

As for threads, if you're using POSIX threads and want your program to be portable, you can use the `pthread_attr_setstacksize` interface to specify the amount of stack space your thread needs, and then as long as you know the calling patterns and over-estimate by a good margin in choosing the size, you can be sure it will be safe.

Answer (score 2):

Depends entirely on your OS and process definitions. Better allocate it from the heap by `malloc` and check the result (which may fail). Allocating failure on stack may cause stack corruption, which you won't be able to catch at run time.

Comment: I've never seen a case where stack allocation failure leads to stack corruption; that's why we get the dreaded "stack overflow" and the program simply halts.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, then you have probably only worked on systems with an [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) that can easily insert a guard page between the stack and text or data segments. :) Smaller systems don't always provide enforcement of separation between stack and text or data.

Comment: @Mark: See the glibc `fnmatch` bug found as part of the Chrome bug bounty system a few months back...

Comment: @sarnold, even smaller systems can easily check the stack pointer against a limit as part of the function prologue. I can see where it might be optional though.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C++ (since the question has that tag) use a `vector<char> buffer(16384)` - that way you get automatic deallocation, but the large buffer gets allocated on the heap.

The only potential drawback is that the buffer will be default initialized. There's a small chance that that might be something you can't afford (though it'll probably be of no consequence).

Comment: I don't need the automatic deallocation anyway. If I decide to allocate it on the heap I'll do the free/delete in the same function a few lines after the malloc/new.

Comment: @Damian manual free is not exception safe and prone to future developer error

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends upon the intended lifetime of the buffer.

If the intention is for the buffer to exist only in the scope of the creating function and the functions it calls, then stack-based is an excellent mechanism to avoid memory leaks.

If the intention is for the buffer to be long-lived, outliving the scope of the creating function, then I would `malloc(3)` the buffer.

My `pthread_attr_setstacksize(3)` says to look in `pthread_create(3)` for details on default stack size; sadly, all I have on my system is the POSIX-provided `pthread_create(3posix)` manpage, which lacks these details; but my recollection is that default stack size is so large that most people who want to know how to set their stack size want to *shrink* it, so they can run more threads in a given amount of memory. :)

Comment: On Linux/glibc, the default stack size for threads is usually gigantic, but on other implementations the default can be very small. That's why I've said code intending to be portable should always set a stack size attribute unless it only uses tiny amounts of stack space (in which case it doesn't care if the stack is too small) and only uses a tiny number of threads (in which case it doesn't care if the stack is too large).

Answer (score 0):

if your code is not used by multiple threads AND it is not re-entrant... then I would just do one malloc at program initialization for that buffer. You will have less of a worry about architecture issues surrounding stack size. You definitely don't want to do a malloc/free per call.

Comment: Whoever inherits this code is going to hate you for using global data. By the way, if you do insist on doing it this way, don't use `malloc`. Just a plain global array will do as well, and it ensures that the memory is reserved before `main` is even entered (so you don't have to deal with failure).